# Images disappear in production build of React because the wrong path is generated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my first time posting here.
I am having a problem with how the production build paths to my images are generated when I run `npm run build`.

I have some logos to display in one of my React components, which show properly in the local server... the problem arises when I deploy to Netlify.

This is the code I use to get them dynamically:

```
currentProject.icons.map(el => {
  return (
    <div key={el.id} className={styles.logo}>
      <div
        className={styles["logo-wrap"]}
        style={{ margin: ".3rem 0" }}
      >
        {el.icon}
        <p>{el.tag}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

This is the result in localhost:
[image: Logos locahost]

But this is the result in production:
[image: Production build logos]

Now, I noticed that in the production build the image src is wrong (./ instead of ../) as when I modify the path in the devtools, the correct image pops up.

My images are in public/Icons but I am importing them to my projects properties so I can render them dynamically.

Before:
[image]

After I add a . to the file path:
[image]

This is the folders structure:
[image]

Right now I was just testing with the React logo, but before I was also trying to import them from src/assets/Logos, but the result is the same in localhost.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you add your folder structure please?

Comment: Hey Anindya, I just edited the original question with it

Comment: I ran into this same problem and could only solve it by importing the photos directly into the component they were needed in. Ex: `import jsIcon from '../media/JS_Icon123.svg'`

Comment: Hey Thenlie, that would work in a the sense of them existing on the page, but I'm rendering the projects dynamically, so I need to import them from the project file for them to be used correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this. Apparently, despite my Netlify production build having a __redirects file specifying that the entry point was `/*    /index.html    200`, to have all the React Router subroutes working properly, I was missing `<base href="/" />` within the `<head>` tags in public/index.html.

Adding this has fixed the image paths and some sub-routing issues (like accessing them directly from a link).

Comment: Thank you @Fra so much it helped me to solve issue with using production react build with esbuild

Comment: Glad this helped someone else 